# Javascript variable in string twig file

Tags: javascript, twig, jsgrid

I need to set value of variable id as in following code,

```
 { type: "control",
                itemTemplate: function(_,item) {

                   var id = item['postId'];
                   var $result = jsGrid.fields.control.prototype.itemTemplate.apply(this, arguments);
                   var $myButton = $("<a style='margin-left:5px;' href='{{ path('updatefull', {'post_id': "+id+"}) }}'><i class='far fa-edit'></i></a>");
                    return $result.add($myButton);
                }
}
```

But this is not working. It shows /+id+ instead of the value of id ( which is like /6 for example). How to solve this?

Comment: Assuming that the stuff in double curly braces gets parsed out by twig on the server side.  So the href attribute is basically hard-coded once it hits the client.  Seems like you need to have the server return just the base part of the url and have your client side code attach the id part on the end.

Comment: The way you mix JS/Twig makes your question unclear for me. I can guess the code in your question is a part of your Twig template but I can not be sure about it, and if it is so, I can't understand what exact  output (rendered output) you want this to generate. If you provide additional information it we might be able to help.

Comment: Consider using  [FOSJsRoutingBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSJsRoutingBundle) as described [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing/generate_url_javascript.html)

Comment: Ok, Appreciate your ideas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Twig template always runs first, on the server, and writes a template which is sent to the client. Then JS in that template can run in the browser. You're expecting JS to declare the variable `id`, then Twig to call `path`, and then JS to continue working, which can't happen. You'll have to get the `id` variable into Twig another way.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I solved it,

```
{ type: "control",
                itemTemplate: function(_,item) {

                   var id = item['postId'];
                   var path = '{{ path("updatefull", {'post_id': 'id'}) }}';
                    path = path.replace("id", id);
                   console.log(path);
                   var $result = jsGrid.fields.control.prototype.itemTemplate.apply(this, arguments);
                   var $myButton = $("<a style='margin-left:5px;' href="+path+"><i class='fa fa-edit'></i></a>");
                    return $result.add($myButton);
                }
```

}